# Update componenet after uploading file JSF

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces

I am uploading a file, namely a picture. I want the picture on the page to update to the new one once it is uploaded. I am unable to get this to work.

I am using the following code to upload the file:

```
<h:form id="fileUploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <p:remoteCommand name="showFileUpload" onstart="fileUpload.show();"/>
        <p:remoteCommand name="hideFileUpload" onstart="fileUpload.hide();"/>
        <p:dialog 
            id="fileUpload"
            header="File Upload" 
            widgetVar="fileUpload"  
            modal="true">
            <h:inputFile id="file" value="#{fileUploadManagedBean.file}"/>
            <p:commandButton value="Upload"
                             action="#{sessionManagedBean.updateDisplay('account')}"
                             oncomplete="hideFileUpload();updateMainPanel();" 
                             actionListener="#{fileUploadManagedBean.upload}"
                             ajax="false"
                             />

        </p:dialog>
    </h:form>
```

The call to `updateMainPanel();` in the `oncomplete` event works for other users. However, for this, it does not. Any ideas on how I can update a component once the file has been uploaded?

Comment: Your question is strange. You don't need that whole `oncomplete` at all given the fact you're using `ajax="false"` and thus you can just use `rendered` and such.

Comment: @BalusC I guess to rephrase it, once the image is uploaded and I do my processing on it, how can I notify a image component (that is in another form) that is needs to update to display the new image?

Comment: You're performing a full (synchronous; non-ajax) request here. In effects, the *entire* page is reloaded as if you're doing a F5. If you're facing a problem with updating an image elsewhere in the same page, then the problem is caused elsewhere. Browser cache perhaps?